# Alignment/spacing issues in the review interface

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

The review interface has recently (in the past day or so, I think) developed some alignment issues: the score and answer count are misaligned, and I don't remember that top section taking up so much space...perhaps the answer count wasn't there because it's also below?  My memory's a bit fuzzy.  Anyway, whatever it looked like before, it's currently kind of broken, visually.  It's visible on any review task—for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/28967678), or [this one with larger numbers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78155) that makes it more obvious (courtesy of [Ollie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/798831/ollie) in the comments).

[image: review interface with misaligned answer/score]

<sup>Screenshot and beautiful red circle courtesy of [Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte)</sup>

I don't *think* this is related to the font changes, but I'm prepared to be told I'm wrong...

Comment: It's a lot more noticeable with more numbers:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78155  Before, they were side-by-side.  Perhaps the new font messed this one up?

Comment: @Ollie Probably not the new fonts; some other undocumented change was the culprit, probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

With the new design for the review interface, this is now fixed: the answers and vote count now appear above the post title and are correctly spaced.

[image: New interface with votes and answer count above the question title]

Comment: The bug has now progressed to the next stage :) [User card is missing padding between username and reputation in review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368899/786798)

Comment: Weird; why do they show user information and score when that is shown in the rendered post body already?

Answer (score 7):

This is the ruleset affected that results in the layout issue:

```css
.s-post-summary--stats {
    --s-post-summary-stats-gap: 6px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    width: 96px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* problem #1 */
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* problem #2 */
    align-items: flex-end;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--fc-light);
}
```

And this is what fixes the issue:

1. Remove the `flex-direction: column;` rule (this realigns the flex items in row order as this is the default for the `flex-direction` property)
2. Remove the `flex-wrap: wrap;` rule (this prevents flex items from wrapping to the next line)

Here is how the summary section looks like before the change (broken):

[image: summary section before the change]

And here is how it looks like after the change (fixed):

[image: summary section after the change]

Comment: The vertical alignment is out with this fix as answer is lower than votes - at least to my eyes.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I only fixed the positioning :) Unfortunately, I didn't have a good reference as to how things looked at the time - someone just pointed the change out to me. But if you need proof that they are on the same baseline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/24YDu.png

Comment: It's my eyes then - or an optical illusion :)

Comment: @DavidPostill - same goes for the numbers baseline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzKYU.png :) But I suspect it feels this way because the border around the "answer" part adds more visual weight than the "hanging in the air" element

Comment: Agreed - it look right with the solid background.

Comment: @DavidPostill - yeah, I think it is a known optical illusion, give me some time, I will find a suitable reference :) With that said, I am not sure if the above fixes all of the changes made, there probably is another small issue with padding changing.

Comment: Don't worry about it - I'm not after a reference - it was just a random observation and I won't lose any sleep over it :)

Comment: @DavidPostill - you just got me interested myself, that's it :) Until you mentioned my perception was that they are both on the same line. I am not sure if this type of illusion has a name or if it is just a variation of the Poggendorff illusion.