# User card is missing padding between username and reputation in review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review, user-card

When [reviewing a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/79194), the padding between the username and reputation seems to be missing:

[image]

The bug was fixed but is now (September 2nd) back; I don't think it's useful to create a new question since it's so soon after the fix.

Comment: Repro'ed in _all_ review queues on SO except "Help and improvement" (which is clear at the moment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed. The UserCard is now right-aligned and padding is better as well.

> Who asked this question
> And how much rep do they have?
> Ahhh… nice whitespace there!

Comment: Right-aligned looks strange. Missing padding is now [back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDE4V.png). Yaakov, please fix it. :)

Comment: Fixed again. For the last time, hopefully.