# Spacing between comment-author link and date-posted link has disappeared

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

This seems to have come up just now.  There's no space between the name and link to the author of a comment, and the date it was posted:

[image]

I found this bug [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369277/798831).  This is kind of annoying if you want to grab the comment link and end up getting the user link instead; can we fix it?

Comment: Test comment for curious users.  It seems OK at first glance, but weird at the second.

Comment: Heh, I thought the bug was in my [Pronoun Assistant user script](https://stackapps.com/q/8440/34061) ...

Comment: Looks like this went out with a recent commit. We're on it.

Comment: @Ollie Ironically it won't be very visible on your test comment, because you're highlighted as OP :)

Comment: The (staff/ mod) badges definitely hide it a bit, but in [chains of comments by "normal" users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BotMb.png) I find it super noticeable.

Comment: @zcoop98 it seems to me that when there are staff/mod badges, the spacing between the mod name and mod badge is non-existent, but there *is* a space between the badge and the timestamp. For regular users, the space between name and timestamp is missing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccdrR.jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fix is in and now live on Meta (soon to be fixed across the network).

[image: fixed]

The issue was that two developers touched the same area in same file, but in slightly different ways that didn't conflict with each other. Both PRs merged "cleanly" without conflicts, but a visual bug was introduced with both sets of changes present.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. That would be a different bug, so it wouldn't have been fixed by my fix for comments. Looks like it was (re)opened [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368899/user-card-is-missing-padding-between-username-and-reputation-in-review-queues), so I'm going to opt to leave this post alone in favor of using the linked post for tracking. Thanks for the heads up!